# How to pass a value from an EnvironmentObject to a class instance in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to assign the value from an EnvironmentObject called `userSettings` to a class instance called `categoryData`, I get an error when trying to assign the value to the class here `ObserverCategory(userID: self.userSettings.id)`

Error says: 
`Cannot use instance member 'userSettings' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Here's my code:

This is my class for the environment object:

```
//user settings
final class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name : String = String()
    @Published var id : String = "12345"
}
```

And next is the code where I'm trying to assign its values:

```
//user settings
@EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings

//instance of observer object
@ObservedObject var categoryData = ObserverCategory(userID: userSettings.id)

class ObserverCategory : ObservableObject {

    let userID : String

    init(userID: String) {

        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("users/\(userID)/categories") //

        db.addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            for doc in snap!.documentChanges {

                //code 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody guide me to solve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `@EnvironmentObject` and `@ObservedObject` are initializing at the same time. So you cant use one of them as an argument for another one.

You can make the `ObservedObject` more lazy. So you can associate it the `EnvironmentObject` when it's available. for example:

```
struct CategoryView: View {

    //instance of observer object
    @ObservedObject var categoryData: ObserverCategory

    var body: some View { ,,, }
}
```

Then pass it like:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //user settings
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings

    var body: some View {
        CategoryView(categoryData: ObserverCategory(userID: userSettings.id))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mojtaba Hosseini, thank you for your answer, it makes total sense and works perfectly. I'm learning and this helped me a lot, appreciate your help!

Comment: One caveat here is, that the ObservedObject gets recreated every time `body` of ContentView will be evaluated. Depending on the given view hierarchy, this may result in some "anomalies" where ObserverCategory value will be unexpectedly reset. I thought about using a `@StateObject` where ObserverCategory will be hold, but without the "direct property wrapper initialisation hack", I cannot think of a way this can be accomplished.